# how can I avoid showing password jinja param in airflow log?

Tags: jinja2, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, secret-key

have a snowflake query in airflow using a password in a jinja template:

```
create stage if not exists {{ params.dest_database }}.{{ params.stg_schema }}.{{ params.stg_prefix }}blabla_ext_stage
url='{{ params.s3_bucket }}'
credentials=(aws_key_id='{{ params.login }}' aws_secret_key='{{ params.password }}');
```

problem is the password shows in query in log - any way of hiding it?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to create a stage on every run of the airflow job? Create it in Snowflake first and then *use* it in the dag run.

If you need to create the stage inside the job then you can use Snowflake's [Storage Integrations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html) for this.

Comment: thanks, these are 2 great options, but was wondering if there is a general way to omit the query string (or parts of it) from the operators log

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that unfortunately. Most creds are either stored in the Connections or Variables of Airflow but all of the rendered SQL will be available in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Provider's operators works with hooks that automatically hide sensitive parts of the credentials in the logs. For example, you can check [`S3ToRedshiftOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2935be19901467c645bce9d134e28335f2aee7d8/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/s3_to_redshift.py#L114) that uses the S3 hook to get the credentials. I don't know how you're using that template, but I highly recommend using the same pattern with hooks to prevent showing the secret key in the logs.

This is what it's showing for me:

```
[2021-08-17 07:40:33,584] {{base.py:78}} INFO - Using connection to: id: redshift. Host: my-cluster-readable.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com, Port: 5439, Schema: schema, Login: my_login_readable, Password: ***, extra: {}
[2021-08-17 07:40:33,601] {{dbapi.py:204}} INFO - Running statement: 
                COPY schema.table1
                FROM 's3://s3-bucket-xxx/folder1/folder2/'
                with credentials
                'aws_access_key_id=MY_ACCESS_KEY_THAT_IS_READABLE;aws_secret_access_key=***'
                IGNOREHEADER 1
            DELIMITER ',' 
            FORMAT CSV
            EMPTYASNULL
            BLANKSASNULL
            ROUNDEC
            TRUNCATECOLUMNS
            TRIMBLANKS
            GZIP;
            , parameters: None
[2021-08-17 07:40:43,105] {{redshift_operators.py:122}} INFO - COPY command complete...
```

As you can see there, both `Password` for the connection and the `aws_secret_access_key` are shown as `***` (automatically by Airflow using the hook).

My recommendation would be to use exactly the same logic like this:

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.utils.redshift import build_credentials_block

# More code here

s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id="your_conn_id")
credentials = s3_hook.get_credentials()
credentials_block = build_credentials_block(credentials)

# Invoke the template here using the credentials_block as a param
```